# Problem during upgrade due to power off

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade Linux from 18.04 to 20.04 but unfortunately my laptop battery got over. When I tried to reopen, it got crashed.

Now on starting there are only three options: Ubuntu, advanced options and system manage. Only black screen appears there. Please help me out, I don't have knowledge of Linux as I had recently moved to linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a release-upgrade is about the worst possible time to lose power. If you are new to Ubuntu, you may lack the skills to recover your system...if it's recoverable at all.

Here's a method of recovery that does not require much skill. But this method does require patience and diligence in each step.

1. Use a different machine to create a new Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Installer (liveUSB).
2. Boot the LiveUSB. Select the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Mount your hard drive.
3. Back up all of your data to some other media.
4. When your backup is complete, clean-install Ubuntu 20.04.